# necessary and sufficient conditions for having an irreducible hyperplane section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $S \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a surface different to a cone. If $S$ is a smooth variety, then its generic hyperplane section is irreducible.  I can imagine a similar result holds for a surface with isolated singularities....

Are there necessary and sufficient conditions over $S$ that guarantee an irreducible hyperplane section?

I understand my question may related to the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem..However, its singular version seems hard, and I cannot find a version for not normal varieties.

Comment: If the ground field is infinite and $S$ is geometrically irreducible, then there are infinitely many (geometrically) irreducible hyperplane sections in $S$. This can be found among various another Bertini type theorems in Jouanoulou "Theoremes de Bertini et applications", Cor. 6.11. I don't think there is a necessary condition for this kind of statements.

Comment: Dear @Cantlog,  you could transform this excellent  comment into an answer, adding the precise hypotheses for Jouanolou's result in order to make your post self-contained.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg: thanks ! I think now it is the job of the OP to look at the details and post an answer. This can be instructive for him/her.